# Discord.js "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to ask what's wrong with the code, cuz I have no idea about it. It says that toLowerCase is undefined.I've tried many ways to solve this problem, but unfortunately I haven't figured anything out yet. The discord.js version is 11.5.1. Well... there's the code:

```js
const { RichEmbed, Client } = require('discord.js');
const { getMember, formatDate } = require('../../functions.js');
const { stripIndents } = require('common-tags');

module.exports = {
 name: 'order',
 category: 'server',
 description: 'Vytvoří kanál, kde se tě zeptá co za druh objednavky chceš..',
 run: async (client, message, args) => {
  const member = getMember(message, args.join(' '));
  const msg = await message.channel
   .send({
    embed: {
     color: 5729279,
     description:
      '<a:AsukaLoading:828186024214659102> Pracuje se na požadavku...',
     timestamp: new Date(),
     footer: {
      icon_url: message.author.avatarURL,
      text: 'Požadavek od: ' + message.author.username,
     },
    },
   })
   .then((m) => m.delete(1999));

  if (args[0].toLowerCase() === 'set') {
    //       ^^
    // error here         
   if (message.content.includes('|')) {
    var sluzba = message.content.split('|')[0];
    sluzba = sluzba.replace('!order set', '');
    var platba = message.content.split('|')[1];

    const AsukaOrder3 = new RichEmbed()

     .setTitle(
      `<:AsukaOrder:835620702559797299> Vaše objednávka byla úspěšně upřesněna!`
     )
     .addField(
      `**<a:AsukaModeration:835266151269138522> Vaše požadavky**`,
      stripIndents`**Služba**: ${sluzba}.
         **Platba**: ${platba}.`,
      true
     )
     .addBlankField()
     .addField(
      `<@826756799062474757> By se měli tvé zprávy co v nejbližší době všimnout a pomoct ti s tvou objednávkou!`
     )
     .setFooter(
      'Požadavek od: ' + message.author.username,
      message.author.avatarURL
     )
     .setColor('#576bff')

     .setTimestamp();
    message.channel.send(AsukaOrder3);

    const esayMessage = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    message.delete().catch((O_o) => {});
   } else {
    return;
   }
  } else {
   message.guild
    .createChannel(`objednavka-${message.author.id}`, 'text')
    .then((c) => {
     let everyone = message.guild.roles.find('name', '@everyone');
     c.overwritePermissions(everyone, {
      SEND_MESSAGES: false,
      READ_MESSAGES: false,
     });
     c.overwritePermissions(message.author, {
      SEND_MESSAGES: true,
      READ_MESSAGES: true,
     });

     const AsukaOrder = new RichEmbed()

      .setDescription(
       `Objednávka uživatele ${message.author.username}, byla úspěšně vytvořena!`
      )
      .setFooter(
       'Požadavek od: ' + message.author.username,
       message.author.avatarURL
      )
      .setColor('#576bff')

      .setTimestamp();
     message.channel.send(AsukaOrder);
     const channel = client.channels.find(
      (channel) => channel.name === `objednavka-${message.author.id}`
     );

     const AsukaOrder2 = new RichEmbed()

      .setDescription(
       'Předtím než ale začneme, tak budeme potřebovat abyste nám sdělil své požadavky. V první řadě, co za server chcete, čím budete platit, jaké chcete parametry a na jak dlouho u nás chcete hostovat. \n\n Pro upřesnění vašich parametrů stačí napsat: ``!order set (Služba) | (Platební metoda) | (Paramtery) | (Doba trvání)`` \n\n Příklad takovéto objednávky: ``!order set Minecraft | Platební karta | 10GB RAM, 30GB Disk | 30d`` \n\n Vaši objednávku zaregistrujeme nejpozději do pár hodin a pokusíme se ji s vámi dokončit a poskytnout vám naše služby! \n\n V případě nějaké chyby v vytváření objednávky kontaktujte: <@574849327650963469>!'
      )
      .setTitle(
       `<:AsukaOrder:835620702559797299> Vaše objednávka byla úspěšně vytvořena!`
      )
      .setFooter(
       'Požadavek od: ' + message.author.username,
       message.author.avatarURL
      )
      .setColor('#576bff')

      .setTimestamp();
     channel.send(AsukaOrder2);

     if (message.channel.name !== `objednavka-${message.author.id}`)
      return message.channel.send({
       embed: {
        color: 161240,
        description: `<a:AsukaError:828188028551299072> Promiň, ale tento příkaz lze použít pouze v kanále s objednávky!`,
        timestamp: new Date(),
        footer: {
         icon_url: message.author.avatarURL,
         text: 'Požadavek od: ' + message.author.username,
        },
       },
      });
    });
  }
 },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot read x of undefined

This error means that you are trying to access a property off of undefined. For example:

```js
const thisIsUndefined = undefined;

// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arbitraryProperty' of undefined
thisIsUndefined.arbitraryProperty;
```

In your code, it could mean one of two things:

- `args` is undefined or not an array. Both `undefined[0]` and `notAnArray[0]` will return undefined (unless you explicitly assign it earlier, like: `notAnArray[0] = 'Hello World'`).
- `args` *is* an array, but there are no elements populating it. `[][0]` will return undefined.

I find it unlikely that your problem is the former, as it most likely would have thrown an error at `args.join(...)`. Assuming it's the latter, the way to fix this would just be to check if `args[0]` exists.

```js
// alternatives:
// if (!args.length)
// if (args.length === 0)
if (!args[0]) {
  return message.channel.send('I am an error message');
}
```

Comment: And if not, what should i do next?

Comment: Just send a message saying, "you need to provide an argument" or something

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot about that.